# Passing data on button press in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm attempting to pass data between two pages.

Here is what I have so far  :
http://jsfiddle.net/8JXTT/49/

So im setting an attribute on the second page using :  $("#secondpage").attr("val", "test value");

And to access this attribute I use : var val1= $(this).attr('val');

But for each 'Link Button' the value should be different.

In this fiddle I'm setting the attribute on the page itself when I should be setting it on the button?

How can I amend the code to pass a unique value associated with each button so that when the button is pressed
the value is accessible on the subsequent page.

Fiddle code:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="firstpage">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>First Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="links"></div>
    <div data-role="footer">
         <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="secondpage">
    <div data-role="header"> <a href='#' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pagecontent" data-role="content"></div>
    <div data-role="footer">
         <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        var button = '<a data-role="button" href="#secondpage" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Link Button</span></span></a>';

        $('#links').append(button);

        $("#secondpage").attr("val", "test value");
    }

    $('#secondpage').live('pageshow', function () {
        var val1 = $(this).attr('val');
        $("#pagecontent").html(val1);
        console.log('val is ' + val1);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems with your code:

1. You're setting value of `val` directly while creating buttons, instead of making buttons set the value once clicked.
2. You should use `$.data` to set data
3. Tricky problem is that when you do create onclick handler for the button, you will probably inadvertently create a 'closure', which means that all click handlers will use same value (last value set) of `i`.

To fix this, you need to
1. Bind a click event to new buttons that will set data of the page
2. Create a method to create a button which will be out of scope of your loop, and call it from the loop

Take a look at changed code, it should work
http://jsfiddle.net/azZVk/12/
Also, it would be beneficial for you to know a little bit about closures. Take a look at this question for example:
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: thanks, I updated your fiddle slightly to clear the div contents when the back button is clicked. This prevents the user briefly viewing the previous div value before its updated : jsfiddle.net/azZVk/13